# Adding custom settings into boot2docker profile

Tags: docker, boot2docker, docker-machine

I'm using Windows machine and running Docker by Docker Toolbox. To run Elasticsearch 5.0, we have to increase the Docker host (boot2docker) virtual memory.

```
docker-machine ssh default
sudo vi /var/lib/boot2docker/profile
# Add this line into /var/lib/boot2docker/profile
sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=262144
# Now exit and check 
exit
docker-machine restart default
```

However, after restarting my Windows machine (docker-machine) and starting the the docker-machine, docker-machine resets the file `/var/lib/boot2docker/profile`.

How to keep this value persistent? I tried to put some options into the `docker-machine create` command via `--engine-env` and `--engine-opt` but have no luck.

Comment: I see you already opened a Github issue for this https://github.com/docker/machine/issues/3859. Have you tried adding a file in `/var/lib/docker` and seeing if it survives reboot? The `boot2docker` documentation https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker says that that folder should also be preserved on reboot. I wonder if it's affected too.

Comment: @GregoryNisbet, I don't want to wait on Github :( . I'm going to check your idea now.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @GregoryNisbet for suggesting. I can resolve it by adding the commands into `/var/lib/boot2docker/bootlocal.sh`.

```
docker-machine ssh default
sudo vi /var/lib/boot2docker/bootlocal.sh
# Add this line into /var/lib/boot2docker/bootlocal.sh
sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=262144
sudo chmod +x /var/lib/boot2docker/bootlocal.sh
```